# How to display something graphically over other apps on Windows 10 using Python?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, win32gui

I want my software to draw a visual on top of screen over other apps (windowed apps, drawing over 'games' is not required), rather than being bound to have my content inside a 'windowed app'. As reference, I want to gain visual that is essentially the same the one Greenshot https://getgreenshot.org/ provides when you take a screenshot.

[The mentioned Greenshot overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp8Zv.jpg)

Is there any way or toolkit(s) that could do this, using Python as the programming language?

Comment: Greenshot actually creates a window that you can see in alt-tab menu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed there is. You are allowed to [download DeskPins](https://efotinis.neocities.org/deskpins/) and everything is self-explanatory afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
window = Tk()
window.attributes("-fullscreen",True)
window.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','white')
window.config(bg="white")
```

this will make any widget with white background or foreground in your window transparent